# How to implement publish/subscribe in Linux without manually bookkeeping the subscriptions list and without userspace helpers like D-Bus?

Tags: linux, sockets, publish-subscribe, multicast

I want something like multicast AF_UNIX datagram sockets (something similarly low-level).

Is there something already implemented in Linux kernel for this? I want it to keep the publish/subscribe logic in the kernel, not in any userspace daemon. One syscall - we publish -- N woken threads - they notified.

```
/* in publisher: */
send(fd, "first\n", 6, TO_ALL_THREADS_PLEASE);
send(fd, "second\n", 7, TO_ALL_THREADS_PLEASE);

/* in the first subscriber thread: */
sleep(1);
recv(fd, buf, 100, 0); /* receive "first" */
recv(fd, buf, 100, 0); /* receive "second" */

/* meanwhile in the second subscriber thread: */
recv(fd, buf, 100, 0); /* receive "first" */
sleep(1);
recv(fd, buf, 100, 0); /* receive "second" */
```

Comment: Have you considered using semaphores?

Comment: How do you suggest using semaphores for this?

Comment: You could put the message you wish to public in shared memory and down a semaphore when it's ready. Other processes or threads that are waiting on the semaphore would be woken up. An interface that lets you publish multiple times with a queue of messages will involve a few more synchronization primitives but can easily be done.